# c++ handy storage of class variables

Tags: c++, class

I have a number of different OpenCV image processing algorithms in one program, being created, and running, depending on user choice. 
I'm trying to unify them to some standard. So each one wrapped in a class like this:

```cpp
class imageProcessor{
public:
    ProcessorParameter_t Param[PARAM_NR];
    imageProcessor();
    void Process(cv::Mat input,  cv::Mat *output);
};
```

where "parameter" variables (user-modifiable, loadable, savable) stored like this:

```cpp
enum ProcessorParams{   PARAM_MARKER_X, PARAM_MARKER_Y,
                        PARAM_NR};

struct ProcessorParameter_t{
    std::string Name;
    union Number{
        float f;
        double d;
        cv::Scalar s;
        bool b;
    };
```

Main purpose of this is to later pass any list of variables to GUI, save and load them regargless of which `imageProcessor` is now in operation, and what variables it contains.

So the question is there any tradiditonal way to do such thing, so I won't have to reinvent the wheel.

**EDIT:**

All `imageProcessor` classes are different, and have different number of variables. Single common thing is `Process(...)`.

union will be replaced by `std::variant`, thanks @Bapo

Comment: I'm unsure about your question but you should be using `std::variant` instead of `union`

Comment: Does every imageProcessor have exactly two parameters?  How do you know what types are active in the union now?

Comment: @john-zwinck, see edit